# RESTful API path for multiple pairs of bus-routes and bus-stops?

Tags: rest, api-design

This is what I'm currently doing and should return a bus timetable for given bus-routes at given bus stops

```
/routes/:routeIds/stops/:stopIds
```

This works for if I want to look up the timetables for multiple routes at a single stop, or multiple stops for a single route, but there's no way for me to specify pairs of specific routes and stops.

e.g.
Multiple stops for a single route: `/routes/100/stops/1,2,3`
Multiple routes for a single stop: `/routes/100,101,103/stops/1`

But I can't tell it I want the timetable for 'route 100 at stop 1', 'route 101 at stop 2'

I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea I can think of is just adding several routes and stops pairs to your path, e.g. `routes/101,105/stops/4/routes/100/stops/4,9` will give you routes 101 and 105 for stop 4 and route 100 for stops 4 and 9.

Alternatively you could abandon the strict REST concepts and just refactor this into a POST request with JSON something like this: `[{routes: [101, 105], stops: [4]}, {routes: [100], stops: [4, 9]}]`. This might also be favourable if you plan to add more query parameters in the future, e.g. getting only accessible routes/stops for certain route/stop combinations.